# Android MaterialButton doesn't change it's color programmatically in android lollipop

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, colors, material-design

I have two `MaterialButton`s in a `LinearLayout` and I change their background color and text color depending on some internal state that I switch to when either of them is clicked. It works fine in all android versions above lollipop. The Initial state for them in all Android versions are working correctly the problem when I switch colors in lollipop.

Here is a photo of the initial state.

[image]

Photo of the correct color in all android versions above Lollipop.

[image]

Photo of what currently happens in Android Lollipop.

[image]

I don't know what case that. I tried many different things but not any of them worked.

Here is the XML code of the layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/handymanServicesButton"
        style="@style/View.RoundedMaterialButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:onClick="@{view::handymanServices}"
        android:text="@{viewModel.isHandymanUser() ? @string/handyman_services_button_label : @string/main_button_label}"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        tools:text="@string/handyman_services_button_label" />

    <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/otherButton"
        style="@style/RoundedMaterialButtonNotSelected"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:onClick="@{view::other}"
        android:text="@string/other_button_label"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The styles that I applied to the button.

```
<style name="View.RoundedMaterialButton">
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/buttonHeight</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">@dimen/cardElevation</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/material_ripple_color</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">24dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button</item>
</style>

<style name="RoundedMaterialButtonNotSelected" parent="View.RoundedMaterialButton">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

The code in the fragment that changes the colors.

```
private fun handymanServicesUi() {
    binding.handymanServicesButton.backgroundTintList =
            ContextCompat.getColorStateList(requireContext(), R.color.colorAccent)
    binding.otherButton.backgroundTintList =
            ContextCompat.getColorStateList(requireContext(), android.R.color.white)

    binding.handymanServicesButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
    binding.otherButton.setTextColor(
            ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.colorAccent))
}

fun handymanServices(@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") view: View) {
    handymanServicesUi()
    viewModel.switchToHandymanServices()
}

private fun otherUi() {
    binding.handymanServicesButton.backgroundTintList =
            ContextCompat.getColorStateList(requireContext(), android.R.color.white)
    binding.otherButton.backgroundTintList =
            ContextCompat.getColorStateList(requireContext(), R.color.colorAccent)

    binding.handymanServicesButton.setTextColor(
            ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.colorAccent))
    binding.otherButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
}

fun other(@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") view: View) {
    otherUi()
    viewModel.switchToOthers()
}
```

Comment: Try `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` instead of `android.support.design.button.MaterialButton`

Comment: The first one is used with androidX libraries. Which is not the case here.

Comment: I suggest you to use the new library instead of the old one which i think might be the case here.

Comment: I tried the new one in a playground app. It also has the same problem.

Comment: setting `backGroundTintList` as `selector` from xml may solve the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create color state selectors for the text and the background. For text's color you can do the following:

```
<!--    under res/colors/handyman_text_color_selector.xml-->

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

Do the same for the 'backgroundTint', say `handyman_button_color_selector.xml`

Next apply them to the layout and use these colors selectors. (*It's preferred to add them to the style*)

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/handymanServicesButton"
    style="@style/View.RoundedMaterialButton"

    android:textColor="@color/handyman_text_color_selector"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/handyman_button_color_selector" />
```

Finally in Kotlin, just toggle the two buttons:

```
binding.handymanServicesButton.isSelected = !isSelected
binding.otherButton.isSelected = isSelected
```

Please review this [issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/179#issuecomment-408229125) too, it has a similar problem.

Comment: This is the best solution. You can also just use myButton.isSelected = true to toggle state

Comment: android:state_checked instead of android:state_selected worked for me